# Who Gets To Vote, How do you vote, and When can you vote?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have looked at the FAQ and am confused about who gets to vote and if a certain reputation is required to vote, and if so, when you earn that privilege.

Comment: Look at the faq again: It tells you about 15 reputation needed for upvoting and 125 for downvoting `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

You earn the ability to vote up at 15 reputation and vote down at 125 reputation. Anyone who meets that criteria can vote on any question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple voting

Everyone with 15 reputation can upvote questions and answers.

Everyone with 125 reputation can downvote questions and answers.

You vote by clicking the upward pointing triangle to the left of the question or answer you wish to upvote, or clicking the downward pointing triangle of the question or answer you wish to upvote.

You can generally vote on any question or answer that you have not already voted on.  Occasionally some questions or answers will be "locked" which disallows voting, but this is rare.

#### Complex voting

However, there are many more types of voting available as you gain more reputation.  Unless otherwise specified both answers and questions are referred to as posts:

At 15 reputation you can Flag a post, noting that it is abusive, spam, offensive, or you can write a note to the moderators asking that the post receive specific attention for a problem. Below the post there's a link for `flag` that you can click to perform this action once you've gained this privilege.  Comments have a little flag to the left when you hover over them.

At 3,000 reputation you can vote to close a question, or open a closed question. Similar to the flag, there's a link below each question labeled `close` or `reopen` when you achieve this privilege.  Closing is a complex topic that is covered in more detail here: [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

At 10,000 reputation you are able to vote to delete a closed question after it has been closed for at least 2 days.  Once enough people have voted to delete a closed question, it is removed from the public website, and from anyone with under 10,000 reputation.  You can view deleted posts if you have 10,000 reputation or more.

At 15,000 reputation you can vote to protect a question, which makes it so only registered users with a small amount of reputation can add new answers to a protected question.

At 20,000 reputation your ability to vote to delete a closed question can be used immediately after a question is closed - you don't have to wait two days, however it still requires more than one vote.